# Need help about drawing on JTextPane

Tags: java, swing

I'm using JTextPane and JButton

If I click the Button, I hope every characters in JTextPane will have a dot under it

[image: e.g]

Is there any way to do this?

The big problem is how to add dots under every characters :(

Answer (score 1):

You can make use of [`javax.swing.text.DefaultHighlighter`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/text/DefaultHighlighter.html), which handles character spacing of a text component in order to do background painting on that component.

```
public class DotHighlighter extends DefaultHighlighter {
    // implementation
}
```

Implementing a custom highlighter is a moderate sized amount of work, but [here's a nice code example](http://www.java2s.com/Code/Java/Swing-JFC/JTextPaneHighlightExample.htm) of an underlining highlighter implementation; you should be able to modify it to draw dots.

Answer (score 1):

http://java-sl.com/tip_colored_strikethrough.html you can use the example of colored strikethrough.

All you need is to draw your line under letters. Just set `Stroke` to your `Graphics2D` instance. (See `BasicStroke` and dash pattern)

Answer (score 0):

Are you using a [monospaced font](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monospaced_font)? If so, it would be possible to create a new label and display a string that is composed only of periods (of the same length as the string in the original label), and display that label a bit lower than the first.

I.E., if your label says `2446`, then you could make a second label that's 5 or 10 pixels lower, which says `....`.

Again, this will only work with a monospaced font- for any other fonts, it would still be possible, but it would involve a more complicated solution (looping through each character, finding its location, and then managing to display a dot beneath it), I believe.